# Bind to Active Directory via SSL using unbound id

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm looking to authenticate with AD using unboundID but I get a serverdown error on the bind action.
The requests work fine when I do this via JNDI instead of unboundID.
I've looked it up online and most seem to have a similar way of doing things.
For e.g. I've referred this answer by Terry
[LDAP: How to authenticate user with connection details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163947/ldap-how-to-authenticate-user-with-connection-details)

This is my code

```
public class LDAPSearch_unboundID {

private static final String LDAPIP = "hostname";
private static final int LDAPPORT = 636;
private static final String USERDN = "adminuser"; 
private static final String PASSWD = "adminpass";
private static final String SEARCHDN = "DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=CC";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    authUser();
}

private static void authUser(String userid) {

     BindRequest bindRequest = new SimpleBindRequest(SEARCHDN,PASSWD);
     System.out.println("101");
     try {
     LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(LDAPIP,LDAPPORT);
     //LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(lco, LDAPIP,LDAPPORT, SEARCHDN, PASSWD);
     System.out.println("102");
     BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
     System.out.println("103");
     ResultCode resultCode = bindResult.getResultCode();
     System.out.println("104");
     if(resultCode.equals(ResultCode.SUCCESS))
     {
         System.out.println("Authentication SUCCESS!!!");
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Authentication FAILED!!!");
     }
     ldapConnection.close();
     } 
     catch (LDAPException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

     }


}
```

Here the output is

> 101
>   102
>   LDAPException(resultCode=81 (server down), errorMessage='The connection to server host:port was closed while waiting for a response to a bind request SimpleBindRequest(dn='DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=CC'):  An I/O error occurred while trying to read the response from the server:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset')
>       at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SimpleBindRequest.handleResponse(SimpleBindRequest.java:718)
>       at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SimpleBindRequest.process(SimpleBindRequest.java:570)
>       at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:2150)
>       at ldapConnection.LDAPSearch_unboundID.authUser(LDAPSearch_unboundID.java:45)
>       at ldapConnection.LDAPSearch_unboundID.main(LDAPSearch_unboundID.java:34)

I've tried this with a couple of other AD servers. What am I doing wrong?

Update: I must add that I'm using an SSL connection.
I've tried updating the ldapconnection part of the code with this.

```
         SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory();
     LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(socketFactory);
     ldapConnection.connect(LDAPIP,LDAPPORT);
     System.out.println("102");
     BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
```

Now I get this error

> 101
>   102
>   LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), errorMessage='80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, **data 57**, v1db1
>       at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:2178)
>       at ldapConnection.LDAPSearch_unboundID.authUser(LDAPSearch_unboundID.java:56)
>       at ldapConnection.LDAPSearch_unboundID.main(LDAPSearch_unboundID.java:39)

I can't see any documentation for "data 57" under result code 49.
The credentials are correct.

Comment: I have this exact same issue. I can't find anything for data hex code 57 for the AcceptSecurityContext I asked the question on Server Stackexchange: https://serverfault.com/questions/859277/what-is-hex-code-57-in-the-context-of-an-ldap-authentication-error-code-49 but so far no answer

Answer (score 3):

I use something like:

```
public static LDAPConnection getNewSSLConnection(String address, int port, BindRequest bindRequest) throws LDAPException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory();
    LDAPConnection ldc = new LDAPConnection(sslSocketFactory);
    ldc.connect(address, port);
    ldc.bind(bindRequest);
    return ldc;
}
```

DO NOT USE "TrustAllTrustManager() unless you are on a CLOSED TRUSTED network.

Find more ways for [SSLUtil](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/util/ssl/SSLUtil.html).